# /usr/local/opt/postgresql/*.plist no match

Tags: installation, postgresql, homebrew

i'm trying to install postgres on my macOS (Monterey 12.0.1).

i've ran `brew install postgres` and the next step is to run `ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/postgresql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents`, but when i do, i get `zsh: no matches found: /usr/local/opt/postgresql/*.plist`

Answer (score 0):

it is the directory address that is causing the issue. change the address "/usr/local" to "/opt/homebrew/" that should solve it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I am new to macOS and I had the same problem.  I installed postgres via “*brew install postgres*”
and when I ran “*ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/postgresql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents”, I got an error.*

The problem for me was that my postgres was installed in different path, after I ran “brew install postgres”, I found the correct path below the **Summary** block:
*/opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgresql@14/14.5_5*

For me worked with the following command:

“ **ln -sfv /opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgresql@14/14.5_5/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents** “

Can you try to replace “*/usr/local/opt/postgresql/*.plist*” with your correct path?